# Subscriptions delayed behind single report running thousands of times

Tags: reporting-services

I find it difficult to think I'm the first to run into this so either my searching ability has truly become sad or the solution is so apparent that nobody has asked before.  Mox nix, I must ask.
SSRS 2012 which has a few hundred reports on it, over a hundred subscriptions and generally speaking, works fine.
This is a Native box, we have a separate box for the SharePoint version.

The monthly 'statement' report is data-driven and is fed over 100K personIds to process and export to pdf on a file server.  The SQL takes .3 seconds, the pdf not much more.  There are just so many of them.  So when this one runs, all others queue up behind it and wait, often for it to completely finish.  Not good. Month end reports are important to a few departments.

My question- can I set the priority of this report somehow (or some other setting) to allow for other reports to process when they are scheduled?

It just boggles my mind that this is even an issue, but it is.

Thanks for any insights-

Craig

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to set an individual report's priority, unfortunately.

I would look at either reducing the number of required executions, if possible, and failing that, you can try manually separating them into batches, and assign a different subscription to each batch.  Sub 1 could handle rows 1 - 5000, sub 2 5001 - 10000, and so on.  Stagger the execution times and it will allow other subscriptions to slip in 'in between' the batch processing subscriptions.

But really, if you truly need to generate 100k-plus reports, I don't think **SSRS** is the best option.  Have you considered **SSIS** instead?

**Dean Kalanquin** has an excellent examination of how subscriptions in **SSRS** work, if you're looking to see what's happening under the hood :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deanka/archive/2009/01/13/diagnosing-and-troubleshooting-subscriptions.aspx

Comment: First, thanks for the input and link, I had not run across Dean before. We have indeed looked into SSIS which is likely the way we will go; it still strikes me as odd that MS doesn't account for this issue though.  If they want to seriously compete with Crystal I'd think they might want to put more thought into how businesses actually build and deploy reports.  Bigger is seldom better.  C'est la vie, no?  Be well-